# Read angular controller from radio button

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to display data in an html table comming from an Angular controller, I have the controller but I want to display that data when I select one of the radio buttons but I don't know  how to achive this.

```
  <div class="radio">
    <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="top30Categories">TY Top 30 Categories</label>
    <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="top10Brands">TY Top 10 Brands</label>
    <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="top10Suppliers">TY Top 10 Suppliers</label>
  </div>
```

I  have my table inside a "div" tag where I call another controller with other data, this data is displayed by default when I load the page

```
<div class="panel panel-default" ng-controller="HttpGetTestController">
```

So what I need is to display different data in that html table when I select one of the radio buttons.

Comment: If you want radio buttons you probably should set the same name for 3 of them, and only use different value.

Comment: Controller is not the best thing to get it worked. Better to use directive with dynamic parameters if needed. Inside directive you can implement any logic you need and it'd be true angular way.

Comment: Can you give us a demo?

Comment: You should check out angular docs regarding radio buttons: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D and make use of ng-change

Comment: @OlegMeleshko hi!

Why the controller is not the best way?

Comment: @kennechu look here https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, but I think this is what you want.

[Here is a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ndus9nJ9j42CrZXfMuf2?p=preview), every time you click on a radiobutton it calls an event.

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" ng-click="radioButton(1)">
<input type="radio" ng-click="radioButton(2)">
<input type="radio" ng-click="radioButton(3)">
```

AngularJS:

```
$scope.radioButton = function(arg){
    alert(arg);
    //Place your code here
}
```

Comment: thank's for your time!

So every value inside the ng-click should be the name of my controllers right?

Comment: @kennechu No the `ng-click="[VALUE1]"` and `$scope.[VALUE1]` those need to be the same. I only added arguments in the `ng-click` so you know in the controller which button you clicked.